# Get the default values for a Library

Tags: javascript, document-library, rest

Is it possible to get the default values for a library using JavaScript?

For example for the column A I've set the default Value 'Pencil'

Comment: What do you mean by default values for library ?

Comment: For example for the column A I've set the default Value 'Pencil'

Comment: For this you need to read each column and find its default value. I will provide the required code snippets as answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the default values of columns you first need to get the columns and then use the get_defaultValue() method to get the default value.

```
this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("ListTitle");
this.fieldCollection = list.get_fields();
this.field = fieldCollection.getByTitle("FieldTitle");
```

Once you get the field you can use the below code to find the default value.

```
defaultValue = field.get_defaultValue();
```

Note : This is not a tested code so might need to correct.